# Keras Functional Api, InvalidArgumentError: input 1 should contain 3 elements, but got 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, text-classification

I am using the functional API of Keras for a text classification task. I am combining word embeddings with metadata, which I both convert into one hot encodings.
I am getting this error when I fit the model:
`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: input 1 should contain 3 elements, but got 2[[{{node training/Adam/gradients/concatenate_1/concat_grad/ConcatOffset}}]]`
I am running a docker container in a K8s cluster, tensorflow is `1.8` and keras `2.2.4`.

**EDIT:**I have already checked that the shape of the nlp data and the metadata is `(55744, 500)`. The layers are like: Metadata layer shape: `(?, 500, 1)` and NLP layer shape: `(?, 500)`.

This is the code:

```
nlp_layer = Input(shape=(int(float(maximum_sequence_length)),), name='nlp_layer');
embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=(len(word_idx_training) + 1), output_dim=int(em_dim), weights=[embeddings_matrix], input_length=int(float(maximum_sequence_length)), trainable=False, name='embedding_layer')(nlp_layer);
metadata_layer = Input(shape=(int(float(maximum_sequence_length)), 1), name='metadata_layer');
dense_1 = Dense(128)(embedding_layer);
concatate = Concatenate()([dense_1, metadata_layer]);
dropout = Dropout(0.6)(concatate);
dense_2 = Dense(64)(dropout);
dense_3 = Dense(32)(dense_2);
dense_4 = Dense(16)(dense_3);
flatten = Flatten()(dense_4);
dense_5 = Dense(int(class_number))(flatten);
activation = Activation("softmax")(dense_5);
model = Model(inputs=[nlp_layer, metadata_layer], outputs=[activation]);
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc']);
verbs_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(verbs_oh, np.float32);
model.fit([x_train, verbs_array],y_train,batch_size=None,epochs=int(float(args.epochs)),suffle=True,steps_per_epoch=10);
```

**EDIT:**This is the error stack:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.pytho
n.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
2019-08-20 21:04:52.171203: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not co
mpiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-08-20 21:04:52.204324: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2399940000 Hz
2019-08-20 21:04:52.206737: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x55f751cbe750 executing computations on platform Host. Devi
ces:
2019-08-20 21:04:52.206794: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3445: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.n
n_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) 
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/code/semeval/g_quote/classify_data_with_metadata_keras.py", line 170, in <module>
    steps_per_epoch=10);
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1039, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 154, in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1439, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: input 1 should contain 3 elements, but got 2
         [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/concatenate_1/concat_grad/ConcatOffset}}]]
root@first-experiment-app-memory:/code#
```

I have already increased the GPU memory, because I was getting `Allocation of 5574400000 exceeds 10% of system memory` and I use `steps_per_epoch`, because the functional API was throwing errors when I was using `batch_size` instead. 
Can someone tell what is the problem with the input/output sizes that causes the `InvalidArgumentError`? Is it in the way the model is build or in the input data itself?
There is also `[[{{node training/Adam/gradients/concatenate_1/concat_grad/ConcatOffset}}]]` in the error message.

This is how the model looks like:

````
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_layer (Embedding)     (None, 500, 50)      1174300     nlp_layer[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 500, 128)     6528        embedding_layer[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
metadata_layer (InputLayer)     (None, 500, 1)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 500, 129)     0           dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 metadata_layer[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 500, 129)     0           concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 500, 64)      8320        dropout_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 500, 32)      2080        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 500, 16)      528         dense_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)             (None, 8000)         0           dense_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 4)            32004       flatten_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 4)            0           dense_5[0][0]        ```
````

Comment: Could you print the whole stacktrace? I know tensorflow's stacktrace is huge, but it's helpful

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just included the error stack.

Comment: What is the shape of `x_train` and `verbs_array`?

Comment: The shape of both is `(55744, 500)`. The shape of the metadata layer is `(?, 500, 1)` and of the nlp layer is `(?, 500)`. I just included this in the question too.

Comment: I train with 55,744 text documents `max_sequence_length`=500, `emb_dimension`=50 and I convert the extra feature `verbs` into one-hot-encoding of size 500.

Answer (score 0):

So, after fiddling around with the code, I realized that I didn't have to transform the input metadata itself to a tensor. I was confused by the fact that when we define a Functional Model in Keras we add tensors in it. 
The solution is first to compute the one hot encoding (500 dimensions) of my additional feature (this would result to a numpy array with rows as many as the input docs, and 500 columns) and use this array as the second input of the model.Then, I also need to expand this array with one mode dimension, because the metadata layer expects to see 3D data.

In the above code, I need to replace

```
verbs_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(verbs_oh, np.float32);
```

with

```
verbs_array = verbs_oh;  # one code encoding of the feature 
verbs_array = np.expand_dims(verbs_array, axis=2);
```

This will change the verbs array from `(55744, 500)` to `(55744, 500, 1)`
Even though the original error is solved, there is another mistake with the code that I cannot quite understand.
After changing `verbs_array` as shown above, if I concatenate like this:

```
Concatenate(axis=1)([dense_1, metadata_layer])
```

I get this error: `ValueError: A`Concatenate`layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 500, 128), (None, 500, 1)]`

These are shapes I currently have:

```
Metadata layer shape: (?, 500, 1)
NLP layer shape: (?, 500)
Emb layer shape: (?, 500, 50)
Dense 1 shape: (?, 500, 128)
```

If I concatenate on axis=2, then I experience no error. However, I am unsure whether this is semantically correct. This is how the first layers look like in this case:

```
nlp_layer (InputLayer)          (None, 500)          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_layer (Embedding)     (None, 500, 50)      1174300     nlp_layer[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 500, 128)     6528        embedding_layer[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
metadata_layer (InputLayer)     (None, 500, 1)       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 500, 129)     0           dense_1[0][0]                    
                                                                 metadata_layer[0][0]
```

Even though I discovered that the initial error is resolved by removing `tf.convert_to_tensor`, I will accept an answer that can correct the whole example and explain what is the appropriate input/output shapes for my network.
**Also**: After concatenating on axis=2, the training of the model became extremely slow. Which makes me think that using two one-hot encodings combined is too complex for my data/network. I switched to using an index for every different value in the feature (so I only have one additional dimension now) and this means that this line

```
metadata_layer = Input(shape=(int(float(maximum_sequence_length)), 1), name='metadata_layer');
```

is replaced by

```
metadata_layer = Input(shape=(1, ), name='metadata_layer');
```

and then when feeding the network, I need to do:

```
verbs_array = verbs_idx;
verbs_array = np.expand_dims(verbs_array, axis=1);
verbs_array = np.expand_dims(verbs_array, axis=1);
```

And the shape of `verbs_array` is (55744, 1, 1), while the shape of the metadata layer is  (?, 1).
These changes result to a similar error:
`ValueError: A`Concatenate`layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 500, 128), (None, 1)]`

I need to add more metadata next to the nlp data, so I would appreciate greatly someone that gives a complete answer to my issues. Thanks in advance.